# Laravel 5 best practice to send data from view to controller

Tags: laravel, view, controller, parameter-passing

I'm working on a rent a car website.

After search, I have a list of all available cars for a period.In this page, i have this details(as arrays):

- Details about the possible rent, like period, pick up date, drop off date etc
- Cars object with every car that is available(name, brand, year etc)

For every car i have a "Rent" button that will send the user from index page to a page with all the details about the car and all the details about the rent + another informations that i will take from database(not relevant for my question).

So, to the controller, i have to send at least this:

- Rent details(a pretty big array)
- Car id

My problem is that i don't know which is the best way to send the data to controller.
The best way i was thinking about it's to make a form for every car and send all the arrays via POST.Is this a good ideea or it's bad to have a form just for this?

I'm thinking about session, but i need this data only in two views that are related, so i can easily send them via POST.

Do you have any good ideea?

Comment: Laravel only implements MVC model view controller so to send data properly is by using form from view to controller.

Comment: Ok.I was thinking that having multiple forms it's not a good ideea.

Comment: No problem just create chunk of views, route and controllers.

Comment: Ok.Thank you very much